Can systemd execute a command *before* a restart?
This is not about ExecStartPre
One use case when tweaking services is to test a config file before restarting the service.
for example.
$ vim /etc/nginx.conf
$ nginx -t && restart_nginx

the equivalent with systemd is to still having to remember the check before issuing a restart.
Is there something that prevents that very-likely human error? something like ExecRestartStopPre? That is, something it will execute before the stop step of a restart?

I wonder if you should be using ExecReload in this case? Add something like this to your service unit:
ExecReload=bash -c 'nginx -t && nginx -s reload'

This will only send the reload (HUP) signal to nginx if the configuration check passes. Unlike restart, this doesn't perform a stop or start on the service.
Instead of running running systemctl restart nginx, you would run systemctl reload nginx.

excellent point! I think that is the best possible with systemd. unfortunately it introduces another annoyance, it fails if the service is not running. restart works. Worse, 'reload' fails with status 1 on both cases (failed execReload, not running) so it's impossible to detect. I guess we still need hacky scripts all around.

I guess systemctl is-active nginx && systemctl reload nginx || systemctl start nginx

thanks again. yep that is the current hacky. no difference at all from the init.d hacks. still very user-error prone :(

Forgetting a step like syntax checking a server config file, implies that configuration's testing and deployment could be automated more consistently.
If doing the check as a part of systemd service verbs is so very unnatural, do it somewhere else.
Such as when the config file is installed. For example, Ansible copy or template modules have a validate parameter, which runs a command on a temporary file. On a failure return code, the file is never copied into place. The older, presumably working, configuration is kept.
Fortunately, systemd service configuration is very modular. You can have your  ExecReload in a drop in file /etc/systemd/system/nginx.service.d/override.conf where it will survive updates to the base unit.  Updates from maintainers who might not prioritize double-checking the user's work at the price of increased complexity of the service.

completely agree with you, but that's not the point. I agree one could edit the file 'blind' and commit it, and wait for a CI job... but one could also just run the CI vm locally, edit the file and restart service and try out payloads, and then commit the file. This is about the second workflow, which will always provide much faster feedback than the former.

i disagree that it is unnatural. Most services provided means for that before systemd. I ended up adding them to the reload verb, which i think was an oversight of everyone creating those unit files and not doing so in the first place, since, again, the services had this in place before systemd.
